Assembly connection creation using Python Rhpsody Api
I am currently working on a script to create an assembly connector using the Python API within Rhapsody. According to the documentation, we can use the AddLink API with its parameters (FromPart, ToPart, Assoc=None, FromPort, ToPort). Here is a portion of my script:
def main():
    rhapsody_app = get_rhapsody_application()
    if not rhapsody_app:
        return
    # Provide the full path to the project you want to open if no project is active
    project_path = "Project.rpyx"

    project = get_project(rhapsody_app, project_path)
    if not project:
        return

    # Replace with your actual starting path and element name
    # starting_path = "PIU_M::SwSubSys::Subsystems::HW_OUTPUT_MANAGEMENT"
    # name_to_find = "Doors_Actuator"

    # Example inputs, replace with actual values
    from_part_name = "XX::XX::XX"
    from_part_path = "XX::XX::XX"
    from_port_name = "XX::XX::XX"
    from_port_path = "XX::XX::XX"
    to_part_name = "XX::XX::XX"
    to_part_path = "XX::XX::XX"
    to_port_name = "XX::XX::XX"
    to_port_path = "XX::XX::XX"
    connector_name = "XX::XX::XX"


    #From Part
    starting_element = find_element_by_path(project, from_part_path)
    if not starting_element:
        return

    found_elements = recursive_search_all_elements(starting_element, from_part_name)
    if found_elements:
        for element, path, element_type, element_guid in found_elements:
            if element_type == "Object":
                From_Part_element = element
                logger.info(f"From Part is: {element.Name} at path {path}, Type: {element_type}, GUID: {element_guid}")
    else:
        logger.error(f"No elements with name '{from_part_name}' found under path '{from_part_path}'.")


    #To Part
    starting_element = find_element_by_path(project, to_part_path)
    if not starting_element:
        return

    found_elements = recursive_search_all_elements(starting_element, to_part_name)
    if found_elements:
        for element, path, element_type, element_guid in found_elements:
            if element_type == "Object":
                To_Part_element = element
                logger.info(f"To Part is: {element.Name} at path {path}, Type: {element_type}, GUID: {element_guid}")
    else:
        logger.error(f"No elements with name '{to_part_name}' found under path '{to_part_path}'.")



    #From Port
    starting_element = find_element_by_path(project, from_port_path)
    if not starting_element:
        return

    found_elements = recursive_search_all_elements(starting_element, from_port_name)
    if found_elements:
        for element, path, element_type, element_guid in found_elements:
            if element_type == "Port":
                From_Port_element = element
                logger.info(f"From Port is: {element.Name} at path {path}, Type: {element_type}, GUID: {element_guid}")
    else:
        logger.error(f"No elements with name '{from_port_name}' found under path '{from_port_path}'.")



    #To Port
    starting_element = find_element_by_path(project, to_port_path)
    if not starting_element:
        return

    found_elements = recursive_search_all_elements(starting_element, to_port_name)
    if found_elements:
        for element, path, element_type, element_guid in found_elements:
            if element_type == "Port":
                To_Port_element = element
                logger.info(f"To Port is: {element.Name} at path {path}, Type: {element_type}, GUID: {element_guid}")
    else:
        logger.error(f"No elements with name '{to_port_name}' found under path '{to_port_path}'.")

    link = project.addLink(From_Part_element, To_Part_element, None, From_Port_element, To_Port_element)
    link.Name = connector_name
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

However, I am encountering the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Arch_Folder\Scripts\Assembly_connector_creator\test_script.py", line 535, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Arch_Folder\Scripts\Assembly_connector_creator\test_script.py", line 531, in main
    link = project.addLink(From_Part_element, To_Part_element, None, From_Port_element, To_Port_element)
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147221503, 'Invalid advise flags', (None, None, None, 0, None))

Could you please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
